# Como enviar un pdf creado por jsPDF a una API en Python

Tags: javascript, python, api, pdf, jspdf

Muy buenas a todos, lo que quiero realizar es lo siguiente quiero recoger los datos por un formulario, crear un pdf en JavaScript y enviarlo mediante una petición POST a mi api para que lo guarde en la base datos.

El problema no logro enviar el pdf estoy usando jsPDF, pero todo lo que encuentro es como descargarlo y no quiero hacer eso quiero crearlo y enviarlo directamente a la api, el tutorial que mas se acerca a lo que necesito utiliza php y en mi caso es con python con el Django así que no me sirve, ne necesito ayuda y me gustaría saber si alguien me puede ayudar.

La funcion que cree en python para guardar los archivos es la siguiente

```
def post(self, request):
        try:
            
            examen=Examen.objects.get(id=request.POST['examen'])
            Archivo.objects.create(nombre=request.POST['nombre'], archivo=request.FILES['imagen'], examen=examen)
            datos = {'message': "Registro Completado"}
            return JsonResponse(datos)
        except Exception as ex:
            datos = {'message': "Error. Compruebe Datos"}
            return JsonResponse(datos)
```

Inicialmente estaba destinada a guardar un archivo ingresado por un input de tipo file por formulario para lo cual la petición se realizaba asi:

```
const archivo = document.getElementById(`inputfile_${index}`).files[0]
      const nombre = String(document.getElementById(`nombre_${index}`).value)
      let FromData = new FormData()
      FromData.append('nombre', nombre);
      FromData.append('imagen', archivo)
      FromData.append('examen', IdExamen)
      try {
        const respuesta = await GuardarResultados(FromData);
        const datos = await respuesta.json();
        console.log(datos)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
```

y mi conexión con la API se realizaba así

```
export const GuardarResultados = async (data) => {
    return await fetch(`${API_URL}resultados/`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: data
    });
};
```

Mi intención original era simplemente en vez de buscar el input de type file sustituirlo con el pdf e enviarlo pero no me funciona simplemente se me descarga y no consigo ninguna solución, ni logro enviarlo; como he dicho antes los tutoriales que he visto utilizan php en mi caso es python. Asi que si alguien tiene una alternativa por favor se lo agradezco